# GRUB menu randomly appears on boot

Tags: boot, grub2, shutdown

For some odd reason, GRUB's "failsafe" mode (NOT GRUB rescue, just the GRUB menu with a 30s countdown) sometimes triggers on my system when booting. I have no idea why this occurs, my computer appears to shutdown just fine, but apparently this is only supposed to happen if a computer shuts down incorrectly. I don't have a dual-boot setup either, so the GRUB menu normally shouldn't be showing up at all. Funny thing is, sometimes it doesn't and my computer boots normally.

I know that the GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT setting can fix the countdown, but why is this issue happening in the first place? It's making me think my computer isn't shutting down correctly somehow.

My current Ubuntu version is 20.10, but this issue occurred on 20.04 LTS as well.

Comment: having the same here too, on two of my pcs sometimes (at random) the grub menu appears on boot after poweron, giving options to boot Ubuntu, or change uefi settings. hitting enter always lets me proceed to normal boot. it seems harmless because i have this for months now, and nothing bad ever happened on either pc regarding the topic.